# What is the best way to execute a MySQL script periodically on Linux

Tags: mysql, update, cron

I want to execute some SQL everyday in a Linux server using MySQL to `UPDATE` some column's values. In order to do that I use the `UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ...` statement.

I want to know which is the best way to do that update automatically?

Is there any method apart from using the cron daemon?

Comment: Search for CREATE EVENT,a mysql cron.

Comment: What's the problem with cron?